# I want to swap an image in imageview with respect to system time

Tags: android

I am developing a schedule application. I want to change image 1 to image 2 when in specific time. And is there any method to get the day of week from system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the second part of your question **how to get the day of week from system** try `calendar.get()` method but remember `calendar.get()` would return an integer based on zero index: sunday = 0 and saturday =6 and rest of the days lie in between 0 to 6.

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Comment: thanx for help @mushahid ...
I am trying to swap image in imageview at particular time interval (eg. 10:00 to 11:00)

Comment: did it solve your problem?

Comment: Ya i got the problem solved.. Once again thanx for help..

Comment: if my answer helped then you can up vote my answer that would be great